# Matlab Stepwiselm: How to extract variables from optimal regression specification (i.e. specification minimizing BIC)?

Tags: matlab, forecasting

I have a data set consisting of roughly 1800 macro-variables with about 350 observations. This data set constitutes the matrix X, whose variance might forecast changes in the US Treasury Yield Curve. To obtain parsimony, we use the 10 first Principal Components of X to forecast changes in the modeled yield curve parameters (this method is called "diffusion index forecasting"). However, we wish to reduce the size of X by removing variables that bear little marginal explanatory power. We do so by using different thresholds. The first threshold is based on the individual significance of each individual variable on the yield curve changes (i.e. remove each variable whose t-stat is >1.65). This method is easy, but it ignores joint significance. Hence, we also employ the stepwiselm function in Matlab with different criteria, including minimizing some information criteria (e.g. BIC) and maximizing R2adjusted. The stepwiselm function searches through the possible model specifications, and chooses the optimal specification based on some criterion.

The problem with the stepwiselm function is that it seems difficult to extract the variables from the optimal specification. Say, for example, that stepwiselm chooses a specifiaction of Yt = a + b1X1t + b2X10t + b3X23t. This means that of the 1800 variables in X, using X1, X2, and X23 minimizes BIC. We then wish to extract X1, X2, and X23 such that we can create a new matrix, X_reduced, whose columns consist of X1, X2, and X23. We then find the Principal Components of X_Reduced, and use the highest order (in terms of variance) PCs to forecast Yt. In the actual problem, X_Reduced will consist of much more than 3 variables.

To sum up the problem: How can one extract and save the variables from the optimal stepwiselm specification?

```
mdl_thresholding = stepwiselm(X, b1_change,...
    'Upper', 'linear', 'Criterion', 'BIC') %Run stepwiselm 
mdl_thresholding.ModelCriterion.BIC %Print the BIC
%Choose variables that minimizes BIC manually, be careful not to include
%the lags of beta1:
i = [8 9 12 15 21 22 24 26 27 28 29 30 33 35 36 38 39 46 49 ...
    58 60 64 65 71 77 78 84 85 87 88 90 91 94 97 98 99 100 ...
    101 102 103 104 106 107 111 117 122 126 127 139 140 ...
    147 153 160 167 183 196 199 202 204 214 216 226 227 ...
    228 236 239 240 243 246 251 255 257 259 264 267 268 ...
    280 281 282 283 288 289 292 295 296 298 302 304 306 ...
    308 310 313 315 316 318 319 321 323 324 325 327 328 ...
    329 332 335 336 337 338 362 372 373 376 378 390 399 ...
    413 414 415 430 445 450 454 459]; %Here I have manually saved the column numbers of the 
%variables chosen by stepwiselm. This is way too time consuming when X becomes larger. 
X_reduced = X(:,i); %Here I extract the chosen variables from X and save them in X_reduced. 
[coeff,score,latent] = pca(X_reduced) %We run PCA on X_reduced
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found a way to achieve the desired output. By running mdl_thresholding .Formula.InModel I obtain an indicator variable of which variables the stepwiselm function has chosen to include in the optimal model specification. I then use this indicator variable to extract the desired columns from X.

```
ind = mdl_thresholding.Formula.InModel; %This is an indicator of the variables used in the
%model.
X_reduced = X(:,ind); %Extract the variables from X and obtain X_reduced
```